# conforming to layout for windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a problem with getting my app to conform to the layout guidance suggest from Microsoft here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872191.aspx

In the section **Page Header** it is suggested that the baseline of the header if 100px (5 units) from the top of the window.  However, I am trying to use a textblock, vertically aligned to the bottom of a 100px grid row, and it seems that there is no reasonalbe way to get the baseline at 100px because there is no way to control the textblock's baseline offset.

Has anyone figured out what to do about this, or what alternate controls might exist that I should be using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the text in the box must be offset in order for it to sit upon the 100px. baseline mentioned in the guidelines.  The easiest way to do this is to use a style that is based upon 'BaselineTextStyle' or 'HeaderTextStyle' in the StandardStyles.xaml file in the 'Common' folder of the solution.

If you look at those definitons, you will see that a RenderTransform is being used to align the text with the baseline, ala;

```
<Style x:Key="BaselineTextStyle" ...>
    ...
    <!-- Properly align text along its baseline -->
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="4"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: ah interesting. You still need everything I mentioned below however.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the default Grid View template, it's 100px in there. 
This is accomplished by defining the grid row as 140 pixels and then defining the margin of the textblock as 40 pixels from the bottom.

The grid height definition

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And the style defined for the textblock is

```
<Style x:Key="PageHeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}">
  <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,30,40"/>
</Style>
```

140 - 40 = the coveted 100 you are looking for :)

If I change the margin to 0 and go from 140 to 100 in the RowDefinition I achieve 100 as per:
[image: 100 pixel baseline]
[image: Measurements]

There's some great design links under Week 1 (Design Guidance) for App Builder at http://aka.ms/stackbuilder (and you get get a free design review as well)

Comment: How is this any different than the current approach of using a textblock in a grid row of 100 and a bottom alignment ?

Comment: It wouldn't be that I can see, just explaining how its currently done in the Microsoft provided templates which conform to the layout spec. The textblock's lower left hand coordinates are indeed controlled by the margins.  When I change the template to 100 instead of 140 and change the margin to zero, my baseline moves to 100. See image additions above

Comment: I note that the real magic here is the style upon which your example is based 'HeaderTextStyle'  In that style, the baseline is achieved with a 'RenderTransform', otherwise the text won't line up.

Comment: Good to know, a good starting point is always the template to ensure you have all the styles.

Comment: Agreed, however, knowing what is actually going on is even better.